# Need to move a small area of the screen

Tags: python, animation, pygame

How do I convert a small part of a surface into an image object?
I am not a python expert at all so, when the docs talk about a class called numpty? and another function called tostring and fromstring, and that was unclear. I assumed from_rect() could help, but also not obvious to me.

I wonder what is the best way to do the following:
I am loading a photo, drawing onto it, then saving it again. But want to convert a small 32x32 area from the middle into a sprite, and then blit that sprite back in, but a few pixels lower down (no transparency or anything fancy). How do I convert a small part of a surface into an image object?

```
size = width, height = 1080, 720
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill(black)
keyboard = pygame.image.load("keyboard.jpg")
keyboard = pygame.transform.scale(keyboard, size)
screen.blit(keyboard, (0,0))
image = screen.getmeaspriteplease(500,300,32,32) # how do I do this?
screen.blit(image, (500,400))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`pygame.Surface.subsurface`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface):

```
keyboard = pygame.transform.scale(keyboard, size)
my_little_copy = keyboard.subsurface(Rect(500, 300, 32, 32)).copy()
screen.blit(keyboard, (0, 0))
screen.blit(my_little_copy, (500, 350))
```

Comment: Thanks @sloth . Not sure who gave the answer a -1, but will try this out in a moment and respond, because it looks like it may cater for my minimal needs. At which point I'll post a confirmation.

Comment: Thank ye!
I changed the last bit to:

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,Rect(500, 300, 32, 32),0) # blank out
    screen.set_clip(Rect(500, 300, 32, 32))    # make a clipping rect
    screen.blit(my_little_copy, (500, 350 + 3)) # move the snipped down 3 px 

which trims the bottom of the snipped image like I wanted.